# type applications and constraint kinds

Tags: haskell

(I'm not entirely familiar with the inner workings of Haskell's constraint solver so this could likely be a rookie question.)

When trying to use type application on GHC 8.0.1, as shown in the following sample code

```
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures, RankNTypes, ConstraintKinds, ScopedTypeVariables, TypeApplications #-}
module Test where

import Data.Constraint

test0 :: forall (b :: *) . (forall a . a -> Bool) -> b -> Bool
test0 g = g @b

test1 :: forall (c :: * -> Constraint) (b :: *) . (c b) => (forall a . c a => a -> Bool) -> b -> Bool
test1 g = g @b
```

it gives me the following errors

```
• Could not deduce: c0 b
  from the context: c b
    bound by the type signature for:
               test1 :: c b => (forall a. c a => a -> Bool) -> b -> Bool
    at Test.hs:9:10-101
• In the ambiguity check for ‘test1’
  To defer the ambiguity check to use sites, enable AllowAmbiguousTypes
  In the type signature:
    test1 :: forall (c :: * -> Constraint) (b :: *).
             (c b) => (forall a. c a => a -> Bool) -> b -> Bool
```

and

```
• Could not deduce: c a
  from the context: c b
    bound by the type signature for:
               test1 :: c b => (forall a. c a => a -> Bool) -> b -> Bool
    at Test.hs:9:10-101
  or from: c0 a
    bound by the type signature for:
               test1 :: c0 a => a -> Bool
    at Test.hs:9:10-101
• In the ambiguity check for ‘test1’
  To defer the ambiguity check to use sites, enable AllowAmbiguousTypes
  In the type signature:
    test1 :: forall (c :: * -> Constraint) (b :: *).
             (c b) => (forall a. c a => a -> Bool) -> b -> Bool
```

`test0` works where there is no constraint involved, but `test1` doesn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have `TypeApplications` enabled, you should enable `AllowAmbiguousTypes` too. If you do so, the error goes away.

The [ambiguity check](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#ambiguous-types-and-the-ambiguity-check) rejects definitions `t` such that no `t :: type` annotation could ever typecheck. For example:

```
test1 :: Show a => Int
test1 = 0
```

If we try to use `test1` elsewhere in our program, we find that there's no way to resolve the `Show a` constraint by way of `::` annotation. Therefore the ambiguity check rejects the definition itself.

Of course, with type applications the ambiguity check becomes meaningless (arguably, it should be turned off by default in this case), since `test1 @type` is fine and completely determined whenever there is a `Show type` instance available.

Note that this is not the same as the famous `show . read` ambiguity. That still produces an error, with `AllowAmbiguousTypes` too:

```
test2 = show . read 
-- "ambiguous type variable prevents the constraint from being solved"
```

Operationally, values with `c => t` types are just functions from `c`-typed instances to `t`. Just defining `test1` is fine, since we can always define a constant function. However, in `show . read` we need to supply instances as argument (or else there's no code to be run), and there's no way to resolve them. Using `test1` without a type application would be similarly ambiguous.